# C++ Implementation regarding this API

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a question regarding the implementation with provided C++ class. With provided C++ class, I mean the design is fixed, can not be changed. So here comes the description.

There are 2 class provided: I only list the related API here. No constructor and no destructor provided, and also no member variable provided. only the interfaces are provided.

```
class A{
    ...(other interface);
    virtual B& func() = 0;
}

class B{
    ...(interfaces);
}
```

My question would be: how should this A::func() be implemented? and the 2 classes should be as much as possible decoupled.

I'm having this problem when perform unit test. my implementation can be seen follow. My idea is: since A::func() returns B&, it means at the time func() is called, an object of class B should exist.

my code:

```
class A_derived : public A{
public:  
    virtual B& func(){
        return *B_ptr; 
    }

    A_derived(){
        B_ptr = new(no throw) B_derived();
        if(B_ptr == nullptr){
            (error)...
        }
    }

private:
    B* B_ptr;
}

class B_derived : public B{
public:  
    B_derived(){
      ...;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying unit test for A_derived with google test and google mock, i feel it is hard to mock the B_derived class, because inside A_derived constructor, the constructor of B_derived is directly called.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement a factory pattern where class A is a factory of class B. Is this correct?

Comment: search for these tags [dependency-injection] [factory] 
In short - do not create B_derived in A_Derived - instead - pass B& to A_Derived - or pass B_Factory to A_Derived